# How to make a Navigation Drawer with these functionalities in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to implement an **Android app** which measures someone's performances in sport activities.

The problem which I have is that I must implement a **sliding menu** from the left side of the screen, where one can change the account on which the performances must be registered.
I don't know how to make the part which is show in this picture.

One can **add a new user** by clicking on add new user button, can **edit the account** by clicking on the pen, and **switch to other account** by clicking on it when it is inactive.

I've searched for info about how to do this but I didn't find anything related to this.

This is how my app must look:[image]

Does anyone have an idea about how to do this or something similar to my issue?

Comment: Combine Two diff. layouts... one for header(USER DETAIL) and other one for list of friends...and use it in nav. drawaer layout..

Comment: instead of saying "sliding menu" say "Navigation Drawer"

Comment: @Prag'sシ: the other people are not friends, are other accounts made on same device, like more people can use the app on same device.

Comment: it was an example.. to make you understand..

Answer (score 0):

You have to Go for [Sliding menu lib](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).

you can use android [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).
Please take look.

Answer (score 0):

There is Suggestion of design for NavigationDrawer..............
This could help you to Create Layout like that...

First Create Navigation Drawer form Here : [Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

and then change some code in Drawelayout.xml(which contains nav. drawer)

**navDrawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.equest.cwely.act"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/actionbar_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/nav_list_header"
            layout="@layout/nav_profile" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#55ffffff"
            android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here,

`<include/>` : I have created one layout and added it into navDrawerLayout file...

`<ListView/>` : second Layout...........